# z-index not working between image and text box

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BradMitchell/k666bmhj/)

I have an image with a text box below. I scaled the image, and it goes over the text box, i wan't the text box to be on top of the image, but it is not working with z-index.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2009/07/101422234.jpg.rendition.200sq.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    This is some text.
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

a:hover .text {
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
}

.text {
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-4px;
  background-color:white;
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code I see you haven't added a position attribute to your elements.. and z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). see here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp ... so try adding position: relative; to both your img styling and also to your .text class before using z-index

Answer (score 0):

try   `z-index` with `position:absolute;`

`.text {
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-4px;
  background-color:white;
  transition:all 1s ease;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index:99;
}`

```css
a {
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

img {
 // transform: scale(1.1);
}

a:hover .text {
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
}

.text {
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:-4px;
  background-color:white;
  transition:all 1s ease;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2009/07/101422234.jpg.rendition.200sq.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    This is some text.
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `transform` on the `img` and `transform` starts a new stacking context. Add `position: relative` to `.text` to start a new stacking context on that element so it will appear on top of the `img`

```css
a {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

a:hover .text {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2009/07/101422234.jpg.rendition.200sq.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    This is some text.
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1;
opacity:.5
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/2009/07/101422234.jpg.rendition.200sq.jpg" width="500" height="140">
```

Because the image has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind the text.

Comment: I'd actually advise against putting a negative z-index onto an element. Semantically speaking, it might be better practice to simply specify a higher z-index for the text

Answer (score 0):

I thought this is what you were after:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container div {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover div {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container div span {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400" />
  <div>
    <span>Image text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```